# jQuery : How to check if NO option was explicitly selected in a select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Is it possible to detect if no option was explicitly selected in a select box?

I have tried these methods but none of them works:

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
  <option value="4">Fourth</option>
</select>
```

Trial 1:

```
alert($('#select option:selected').length); // returns 1
```

Trial 2:

```
alert($('#select option[selected=selected]').length); // returns 1
```

Trial 3:

```
alert($('#select option:selected').attr('selected')); // returns 'selected'
```

Any ideas SO people?

Comment: You're always going to have an option selected because by default it will always select the first item on page load. You need to add a `<option value=""></option>`, and test if the value is empty.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I prepend an <option>None selected</option> to the select box on runtime. But it never comes by ':selected'. Does jQuery ':selected' not consider dynamically added options?

Comment: You assume correctly. Prepend is adding it AFTER dom load, so the first item selected will be the item that was first @ the time of DOM load.

Comment: wrote this just for fun hence sharing (demo sorta test case for your question) : http://jsfiddle.net/g3qc9/6/ liked all the answers specifically @david's , cheers!

Comment: There's no reason to do any of the suggestions on this page. Your issue is with the jQuery's .prepend() method. Simply use `<option value="" selected=selected> None Selected</option>` in your prepend and it will propagate correctly. Everyone else is crazy.

Comment: Similar question here, this solution worked nicely for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018365/js-jquery-how-to-check-whether-dropdown-has-selected-values

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try This:

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
  <option value="4">Fourth</option>
</select><input type="button" id="btncheck" value="check"/>
```

Use this JS:

```
$('#btncheck').click(function(){
     if ($("#mySelect ")[0].selectedIndex <= 0) {
                alert("Not selected");
            }
    else
        alert("Selected");
});
```

​It will check if your dropdown was selected.

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aPYyt/

​Hope it helps!

PS: You will have to make **first value** as default value.

Comment: Maybe relevant to add that the selectedIndex property returns `-1` when nothing is selected:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/selectedIndex

Comment: RE: -1 value when nothing is selected - that is NOT what I am seeing in Chrome or Firefox. I see a return value of 0 when nothing is selected.

Answer (score 6):

This is how a *normal* select element works: the first option is selected if no other option has `selected` attribute set. The simplest workaround is to add an *empty* option as the first option, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  console.log($("#mySelect").val());
  console.log($("#mySelect").get(0).selectedIndex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="">-- select an item --</option>
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
  <option value="4">Fourth</option>
</select>
```

then test one of these conditions:

```js
$("#mySelect").val() === "";
$("#mySelect").get(0).selectedIndex === 0;
$("#mySelect option:selected").index() === 0;
```

Comment: this option helped `$("#mySelect option:selected").index() == 0` with a slight variation in my particular case `$("#mySelect option:selected").index() <= 0` Beautiful!

Answer (score 3):

A select box always has a value. If you don't manually change from the default value, you still have a value. For checking for *explicit* changes, as you say, you could monitor `change`:

```
$('#select').change(function() { $(this).data('changed', true); });
```

Your condition, then, would be:

```
if(!!$('#select').data('changed')) { ... }
```

The more common way of achieving something similar would be to insert a placeholder value at the top:

```
<option value="0">Please select one item</option>
```

... and test for

```
$('#select').val() == '0'
```

If you need to find out whether the select has been changed from its original value, i.e. the above test, but making sure that the user doesn't switch back to the default, you coul simply store the original value at page load:

```
$('#select').data('original-value', $('#select').val());
```

And check for

```
$('#select').val() != $('#select').data('original-value');
```

Answer (score 0):

By default whatever option comes on index 0 is considered by browser as selected. The solution to problem would be inserting a dummy option at index 0 and before form submission you can validate it using something like

`if($("#selectBox option").index("option:selected")>0)`
   `$("#myForm").submit();`

Answer (score 0):

```
var $inputs_select_options = $('option:selected');      

// remove empty(first option as default , value=="" ) options:
$inputs_select_options = $inputs_select_options.filter(function() {
    return this.value.length; //check by length value
});
```